# Accessing the last few rows of a matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I view (or access) the last 10 rows of a matrix?

Note that the matrix size (i.e., the number of rows) is changing: rows= 50, 100 150...

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `end` operator to see the last ten rows, like such:

```
array(end-9:end,:)
```

This shows rows from 'last one'-9 (e.g. from 41 if there's 50 rows) till the last row (e.g. 50), and all columns.

Comment: You might want to be a little careful here: If the matrix has less than 10 rows `end-9` is outside the matrix. Use `array( max(1,end-9):end, : )` instead.